# C Codelite compile error

Tags: c, mingw32, codelite

I just installed CodeLite onto a brand new PC and I am not able to compile anything. I want to write a console application in C

```
Simple Executable (gcc)
Compiler: gnu gcc
Debugger: GNU gdb debugger
```

However, I can't even build a default "hello world" application. All I get is this error:

```
  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile
  'mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

Now I "googled" this and found out, I have to set up mingw32-make, (which I didn't have to do on 3 other computers) but I can't find a tutorial on how to do that.

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `ming32-make.exe`? Looks like your environment variables need to be configured to include the folder path to mingw32 to do it the way you tried.

Comment: Have you tried logging off and back on again so that environment variables set by the installer can take effect?

Comment: Problem was as Eran said bellow with compiler not being installed in the first place. I foolishly skipped the "setup wizard" after first start and that was a mistake :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeLite does not install MinGW for you. You need to do it for yourself.
Obviously, CodeLite does not know where to find `mingw32-make.exe` otherwise, it wouldn't use just `mingw32-make.exe` instead it uses the full path to `mingw32-make`, something like `C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\mingw32-make.exe`

What you need to do is:

- Run CodeLite setup wizard again from Help->Run the Setup Wizard
- Follow the steps (5 in total), pay close attention to the **Setup Compilers** step

  - If you have installed MinGW before, just click on the **Scan** button
  - If you don't have, click the **Install** button
- Open your project settings->General page and select the compiler you just installed in the **Compiler** field

Comment: Thank you very much! It's all okay now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make enables the end user to build and install your package without knowing the details of how that is done -- because these details are recorded in the makefile that you supply.
Make figures out automatically which files it needs to update, based on which source files have changed. It also automatically determines the proper order for updating files, in case one non-source file depends on another non-source http://file.As a result, if you change a few source files and then run Make, it does not need to recompile all of your program. It updates only those non-source files that depend directly or indirectly on the source files that you changed.
Make is not limited to any particular language. For each non-source file in the program, the makefile specifies the shell commands to compute it. These shell commands can run a compiler to produce an object file, the linker to produce an executable, ar to update a library, or TeX or Makeinfo to format documentation.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer